# Azure Board (DevOps) Reports

Tags: scrum, jira, scrum-master, tfs, vsts

I am looking for out of the box "Scrum" reports (velocity, burn-down, sprint report) that use story points, in the tool Azure Boards/DevOps (formerly known as VSTS).

I played with "Analytics Views" that tie into Power Bi, but nothing even close for the type of data/reports I am trying to pull. I have found dashboard widgets for burn-down & velocity (screenshot). But this data is really only helpful over time, which is the issue...

So my first question is - does anyone know of a way "out of the box" to pull velocity and burn-down charts historically. Something similar to Atlassian (JIRA) Sprint report would be ideal.

Secondly, if not available out of the box (which I suspect), has anyone be able to recreate these concepts (velocity, burn-down, and/or sprint report) using the Analytics Views and Power Bi? I am somewhat familiar, but have no idea how to start this query.

Lastly - any other route to accomplish the goal.

These features seem pretty basic - so I am hoping someone has come across this!

Comment: Analytics View + Power BI is the way to go. There are no pre-baked reports.

Comment: You can create Dashboard widgets to drive most of the questions you have.

Comment: The Jira Reports don't have a direct equivalent in Azure DevOps at the moment.

Answer (score 2):

There are a variety of [OOB charts in Azure DevOps](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/dashboards/widget-catalog?view=azure-devops). Some simple ones can be viewed under "Charts" after you run a query for your current sprint. (I don't know why they don't display in the Sprint view):

[image: Azure DevOps query for "current sprint"]

After you run the query click Charts -- you can then view/edit a number of different charts.

[image: Azure DevOps chart based on query for "current sprint"]

Of course you can get fancy with Analytics views and integration with Power BI. But these sound more like what you're after.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

There's also AgileInsights, this comes with a built in Sprint Report, much like Jira's. Try it out here: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Curamobile.teamhealth